# Need replacement for Windows Live Mail

Tags: windows-10, email-client

I have a user in my organization that uses Windows Live Mail 2012 on Windows 10.

Among the features needed are connecting to arbitrary e-mail servers, handling multiple accounts, having folders, marking of priority e-mails to be read later, working with that "tell I read the e-mail" feature, and most importantly of all features: supporting multiple signatures.

Microsoft is trying very hard to kill WLM, it is "not supported" in Windows 10, their e-mail servers don't communicate with it, and they launched an update in december that broke the software completely... That particular update is NOT installed, but WLM today kept freezing randomly all the time on the machine.

The thing is, I personally never used e-mail clients such as this, even WLM I am not much sure how to use... So I am completely clueless on what to do.

Comment: I would recommend Mailbird which is modern and very similar to Windows Live Mail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been using Mozilla's [Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/thunderbird/) email client for years.

It works quite happily on Windows 10, running different accounts connecting to various servers, POP3 and IMAP.

The range of [features](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/thunderbird/features/) is as good as any email client.  Including your requirement for [multiple signatures](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/signatures).

Comment: Definitely my favorite (free) email client! Highly recommend

Comment: since you made the answer, it has been in use in production, with lots of hiccups (like it refusing to change fonts, crashing randomly because of a plugin that was only intended to change text bg color, or its extreme slowness due to it loading ALL e-mails of a folder into RAM when you need to use that folder), but less than Windows Live Mail, so I accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird gives you another reason to move from Windows Mails. WIndows mail exports emails in EML format. Thunderbird imports this mail format much easily.